# How to make countdown timer not reset when refreshing the browser in ASP.NET C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET C#. Below is the countdown timer js code.

How can I prevent the timer from resetting on page refresh with this Js and ASP.NET c# code?

```js
function progress(timeleft, timetotal, $element) {

    var progressBarWidth = timeleft * $element.width() / timetotal;

    $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 500).html(Math.floor(timeleft / 60) + ":" + timeleft % 60);

    if (timeleft >= 0) {

        setTimeout(function () {
            progress(timeleft - 1, timetotal, $element);
            }, 1000);

        timerRemain = timeleft; 
    }
};

// progress(60, 60, $('#progressBar')); // 60 in sec
progress('<%=timer%>', '<%=timer%>', $('#progressBar')); // here  iam passing value from back end.
```

Comment: use Cookies or session state refer to this article https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/

Comment: You should use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to hold value in JS, but if you want to hold it in ASP.Net you can also use `Session` or `ViewState` or ..., anyway there are many ways to hold value and retrieve it after page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use localstorage for saving time interval. localstorage data does not get cleared unless user explicitly removes.
you can use below code to save and retrieve from browser localstorage.

```
    function SaveToLocalStorage(){
    var date = new Date();
    var currentTime = { sec:date.getSeconds(), min:date.getMinutes(), hr:date.getHours() };
    localStorage.setItem("currentTime", JSON.stringify(currentTime));
}

function RetrieveFromLocatlStorage(){
    var myObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentTime"));
    console.log(myObj);
}
```